# Get window.location.reload to load only once in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a working window location reload that only works in this state, when I try and set it to before `Enter`, after `Enter` etc it just flickers and loops round and round.

How can I get the following code to reload, just once and once only when I enter the page?

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function() {
        $window.location.reload(true);
    })
})
```

I know I will need to add `$ionicView.afterEnter` but it is the javscript code needed to execute only once that I am struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

simple logic is to maintaining a global bit & based on its `truthy/falsy` value control the reloading of your page.

this is achieved in two ways:

1. add to `$routeScope.reloadBit` within `angular.module.run()` & refer else were in your controller.
2. Create a service and return a shared object `reloadBit`.